# How much schach would be required for a Leviathan succah?

Tags: halacha, midrash, sukkah, schach

Preface - While this question may appear humorous, it is **not** "Purim Torah".

On Shmini Atzeret, there is a short "good-bye" to the Succah prayer which includes the wish that we should merit, next year, to sit in a succah composed of Leviathan skin.

I know very little about this Midrash, other than my understanding that the Leviathan is a gigantic sea monster and during the time of the Mashiach (?) all the righteous people will have a big feast in a succah composed of Leviathan skin.

I assume that if this were to be a "valid" succah, it needs schach, unless the term "succah" in this sense, is metaphoric. If it is a real succah, about how much shcach might be needed, and what would the schach be composed of? Is there any discussion about this?

(I was tempted to put a request for Leviathan skin on my neighborhood bulletin board, BTW :-)

Comment: Why do you think that the requirements would different from those of any other valid succah (assuming, as you do, that the "succah" mentioned is the Succot kind).

Comment: @IsaacMoses Perhaps, my question is unclear (let me know). I am not seeking "requirement". I am asking regarding the size of the leviathan, and how large this succha would prob. be, based on the description of the Leviathan. It's an area that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/31572/what-was-is-the-leviathan-as-described-in-tanach-and-rabbinic-literature

Comment: "Enough Schach to have more shade than sun" would be my guess. :-) But I'm sure it's metaphorical.

Comment: See also http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/55124/5323

Comment: @DanF This seems like a _very_ roundabout way of asking "How big is a Leviathan?" which also brings in lots of other complications such as halachot about sukkot.  Why not just ask that question?

Comment: Even if you know the surface area of a Leviathan (how much skin it has), the amount of skhakh you would need for a sukkah made out of its skin (assuming you must use every single square inch of skin) would depend on the shape of the sukkah.

Answer (score 1):

The footprint of a *suka* need not be convex. In other words, there can be two points inside a *suka*, equally high off the ground, such that the straight line segment joining those two points includes some points outside the *suka*. Proof: *Mishna B'rura* 634:1 forbids such a case where the local convex area is less than seven handbreadths by seven handbreadths — which implies it's okay otherwise.

Therefore, one can have a *suka* whose walls have area as large as one likes — simply wave them in and out in a high-frequency sinusoidal wave or some approximation to a space-filling curve if you prefer — but which *suka* fits within a small square footprint (and people don't sit too close to the walls, to avoid the problem mentioned in the *Mishna B'rura* cited above).

So the answer to your question is: "not very much *s'chach*, necessarily".

---

That said, I have no reason to think the *suka* would need to be valid for *Sukos*, and, therefore, may not need *s'chach* at all, as [mevaqesh](/users/8775/mevaqesh) points out in a comment on the question. Moreover, as [Monica Cellio](/users/472/monica-cellio) points out there, the walls may not use the entirety of the animal's hide.